# Why does python urllib2 urlopen return something different from the browser on API call

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, urllib2, urlopen

I need to routinely access and parse XML data from a website of the form:

```
https://api.website.com/stuff/getCurrentData?security_key=blah
```

I cannot post the actual connections because of the secure nature of the data. When I put this url into my browser (Safari), I get XML returned.

When I call this through urllib2, I get junk.

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("https://api.website.com/stuff/getCurrentData?security_key=blah") 
s = f.read()
f.close()
s
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xc5\x96mo\xda0\x10\xc7\xdf\xf7SX\xbc\xda4\x15\xc7y\x00R\xb9\xae\xfa\xb4U\x1a-\x150M{5y\xe1\x06V\x13\x079\x0e\x14>\xfd\x9c\x84\xb0\xd2\xa4S\xa4L\xe5\x95\xef\xeeo
```

This post [Urllib's urlopen breaking on some sites (e.g. StackApps api): returns garbage results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028426/urllibs-urlopen-breaking-on-some-sites-e-g-stackapps-api-returns-garbage-re) seems to be a similar problem, but it refers to JSON instead of XML. Following the instructions to look at headers, I think that I am getting GZIP data returned. {I did the test suggested, posted here}

```
req = urllib2.Request("https://api.website.com/stuff/getCurrentData?security_key=blah",
                      headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, identity'})
conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)
val = conn.read()
conn.close()
val[0:25]
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xc5\x96]o\xda0\x14\x86\xef\xfb+,\xae6M'
```

In that post, there was some suggestion that this could be a local problem, so I tried an example site.

```
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.python.org")
s = f.read()
f.close()
s
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n\n\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">\n\n<head>\n  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n  <title>Python Programming Language &ndash; Official Website</title>\n
```

This works just fine, so I think it has something to do with the site API that I am actually trying to access.

This post [Why does text retrieved from pages sometimes look like gibberish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271484/why-does-text-retrieved-from-pages-sometimes-look-like-gibberish) suggested that I might need to do something with "Selenium" but then the poster said the problem "fixed itself" which does not help me figure out what is wrong.

Am I not able to use python to download secure data?
Do I need to use something different besides urlib2 and url open?

I am running python 2.7 on Mac OSX 10.7.5

Comment: Check the headers; does the server return *compressed* data?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, @MartijnPieters -- I'm still new to this. But...this is what I get when I ask for headers `print req.headers
{'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, identity'}`

Comment: Those are the headers you sent. Check `conn.info().headers` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving GZIPped, compressed data; the server expressly tells you it does with `Content-Encoding: gzip`. Either use the `zlib` library to decompress the data:

```
import zlib

decomp = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
data = decomp.decompress(val)
```

or use a library that supports transparent decompression if the response headers indicate compression has been used, like [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: EXCELLENT! The zlib works, but I'll go track down requests for perhaps a cleaner solution. I tried earlier to understand requests, but I was not entirely sure that would be a better approach than `urllib2` and `urlopen`.

Comment: @Jessi: `requests` is *far* cleaner than `urllib2`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`'\x1f\x8b\'` is indeed the magic header for gzip, so you are getting gzip data back.

In your second example you explicitly accept gzip encoded data, change that to `'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: When I get rid of gzip in the accept, @LennartRegebro, I get the same stuff.   `req = urllib2.Request("https://api.website.us/stuff/getCurrentData?security_key=blah",
                          headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'})

conn = urllib2.urlopen(req)

val = conn.read()

conn.close()

val[0:25]
 '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xc5\x96Qo\xda0\x10\xc7\xdf\xfb),\x9e6M'`

Comment: I thought they looked familiar @MartijnPieters.  Here is what happens. `conn.info().headers      ['Date: Fri, 31 May 2013 14:13:01 GMT\r\n',
 'Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)\r\n',
 'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.18\r\n',
 'Content-Encoding: gzip\r\n',
 'Content-Length: 645\r\n',
 'Connection: close\r\n',
 'Content-Type: text/xml\r\n']`  So, it definitely looks like gzip

Comment: @Jessi: It's hard to say without testing, but it seems to me the server is broken and will always send gzip. You'll have to unzip it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947120/does-python-urllib2-will-automaticly-uncompress-gzip-data-from-fetch-webpage (or even better, as Martijn suggested, use requests).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can use Martijn's suggestion.